# How to open subprocess in services session?

Tags: python, windows, session, subprocess, popen

I have a Windows scheduled task written in Python. It opens standalone processes in the background as follows:

```
startupinfo = subprocess.STARTUPINFO()
startupinfo.dwFlags |= subprocess.STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW
subprocess.Popen(appName,
    startupinfo = startupinfo,
    creationflags = subprocess.CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE,
    close_fds = True)
```

It looks like the child processes inherit the parent's session id.
If the user is logged on in an interactive session, the task and its child processes run under the user's session. If the user is not logged in, the task and its child processes run in the services session (in task manager - Session ID 0).

**Is there any way to open processes in the services session always, independent of the parent's session?**

The problem is that when the logged on user's session ends, all child processes are terminated.

Comment: @eryksun, thanks for idea, but yes, there are reasons to run under the user. I cannot use SYSTEM account here.

Comment: Try creating an on-demand task using `schtasks /create /f /sc once /st 00:00 /sd 01/01/1900 /np /tn TASKNAME /tr "TASKRUN 'quote using single quotes'"` -- replacing the `/tn` task name (use a unique name) and `/tr` command line. The `/np` no password option makes the task use an [S4U logontype](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383016), i.e. it runs in the services session (as the creating user since `/ru` isn't used to set the user). You can run the task on demand using `schtasks /run /tn TASKNAME`.